# Can't send MMS programmatically using vonage

Tags: node.js, mms, vonage

I have used this reference(https://developer.vonage.com/en/messages/code-snippets/mms/send-mms?lang=javascript) for sending MMS

```
vonage.messages.send(
  new Image({ "url": IMAGE_URL }, TO_NUMBER, FROM_NUMBER)
)
.then(resp => console.log(resp.message_uuid))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I am 100% sure I used valid credentails, because I can able to send sms. Only mms got failed.

I got below error

```
data: {
  type: 'https://developer.nexmo.com/api-errors/#unathorized',
  title: 'You did not provide correct credentials.',
  detail: "Check that you're using the correct credentials, and that your account has this feature enabled",
},
```

After searching I find this link (https://api.support.vonage.com/hc/en-us/articles/4412210010644-Why-am-I-getting-401-Unauthorized-error-when-sending-messages-with-Messages-API-version-1-)

As per the link I used api version 1 and my from number also linked with my application created in vonage account.Their statement was I should must use JSON Web Token (JWT) authentication; otherwise, you will get 401 unauthorized errors.

Is the vonage server sdk didn't use JWT authentication?

```
 const { Vonage } = require('@vonage/server-sdk')
```

Then guide me how to do with @vonage/server-sdk and JSON Web Token used to send MMS from my node.js ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you per chance take a look at https://developer.vonage.com/en/getting-started/concepts/authentication#json-web-tokens-jwt

Comment: The Vonage server SDK should automatically manage the authentication process, including generating and using the required JWT. Are you sure that the feature for sending MMS is enabled for your Vonage account?

Comment: @NazrulChowdhury Yes the mms feature is enabled.